# jQuery taking live input and then simulating typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some issues with simulating live typing with jQuery.  My Javascript is as follows (with a live demo [here](http://jsbin.com/eVOcOku/1/edit/)).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var keystrokes = [];
    var value = "";
    var counter = 0;
    window.setInterval(pushKeystrokes, 100);
    function pushKeystrokes() {
        keystrokes.push({
            value: value
        });
    }
    $("#test").keyup(function () {
        value = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $("#test").val("");
        $.each(keystrokes, function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $("#test").val(keystrokes[counter].value);
            }, 100 * counter);
            counter++;
        });
    });
});
```

This is supposed to wait for input to a text field called `test`, and as soon as a button is clicked, it should clear that text field and simulate typing the characters the user typed in real-time.  For some reason, my call to `setTimeout` only produces the very last value in the array.

However, if I set `Math.random` as the value of the text field in the `setTimeout` instead of `keystrokes[counter].value`, it seems to update fine every 100 milliseconds as it should.  What exactly am I doing wrong? I'm guessing it has something to do with scope.

**Edit:**

Sorry I wasn't clear.  I would like to preserve delays in user action, i.e. waiting a few seconds before typing, typing words at different speeds, etc.  Is this still possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the code you posted in your JSBin, modified a few things here and there.
The logic behind the rewritten script is added in the form of comments.

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/eVOcOku/5/)

Comment: I wanted the actual typing to be in real time.  I know what you're trying to do as I saw solutions like that, but this does not deal with delays in user actions, i.e. waiting a few seconds before typing the next word/char.

Comment: You want the delay to be the same as the user? as in every character typed exactly at the phase of the user? this can be done to ;) or just increase the setTimeout time to be something random

Answer (score 0):

Try this example http://jsbin.com/eVOcOku/4/.

In your example you have additional issue with timeInterval.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems you're having here, some to do with unnecessary code, and some to do with the nature of setTimeout

First of all the pushKeyStrokes() function seems dodgy; it only checks every 100 ms? Besides, it's not needed because later you can just go through the string provided by the input once the button is pressed, and you can do that using charAt.

Secondly, you're referring to the value "counter" within your setTimeout function, but by the time that function is called the counter value will have reached the length of the input string; counter++ will already have been called every time before the first call to the character display function is even made!

In any case, I modified your JS Bin; hope it makes sense and let me know if you have any questions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var value = "";
  $test = $("#test");

  $("#button").click(function() {

    value = $test.val();
    $test.val("");

    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
    {
       window.setTimeout(addChar, 100 * i, value.charAt(i));
    }

    function addChar(char)
    {
      $test.val($test.val() + char);
    }

});
```

});